# Responsive collapsible tables one at a time:

Tags: javascript, html, css

First time on stackoverflow, so please don't beat me up too much.

I'm working with an existing code from codepen and trying to figure out how to make the tables expand one at a time.

Currently if we click on more than one "+" icon, they remain open, wondering how we can make it so that previous items expanded will close when clicking on the "+" sign.

I tried adjusting the layout here to no avail:

```
$('.js-tdToggle').on('click', function(){
    if(window.innerWidth < 681){
        $(this).toggleClass("fa-plus-square fa-minus-square");
        var trParent = $(this).parent().parent();
        trParent.toggleClass("collapse");
    } else {
        $(this).toggleClass("fa-plus-square fa-minus-square");
        var tdParent = $(this).parent();
        tdParent.next("td").toggleClass("collapse");
    }   
});
```

[Original Source Codepen](https://codepen.io/dubrod/pen/OVyJoG)

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add code where you do the opposite action on every other toggle. JQuery's `.not()` function is very useful for this. With my changes the JavaScript looks like this:

```
$('.js-tdToggle').on('click', function() {
  var $otherToggles = $(".js-tdToggle.fa-minus-square");
  if (window.innerWidth < 681) {
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-plus-square fa-minus-square");
    $otherToggles.not(this).toggleClass("fa-minus-square fa-plus-square");
    var trParent = $(this).parent().parent();
    trParent.toggleClass("collapse expand");
    var $otherParents = $otherToggles.parent().parent();
    $otherParents.removeClass("expand").addClass(" collapse");
  } else {
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-plus-square fa-minus-square");
    $otherToggles.not(this).toggleClass("fa-minus-square fa-plus-square");
    var tdParent = $(this).parent();
    tdParent.next("td").toggleClass("collapse expand");
    var $otherParents = $($otherToggles).not(this).parent();
    $otherParents.next("td").toggleClass("expand collapse");
  }
});
```

You can refer to my forked pen to see it in action: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/etarhan/pen/oOxeEL)

Comment: this works flawlessly... but just relealized that when I change the  output view to say like Galaxy 5 using chrome dev tools, it appears that the icons don't work properly. However, when viewing in Ipad it works perfectly, so I'm wondering if there should be size check added into the js file or css to check if the screen dimensions changes.

Comment: @zmerlin I'm sorry I should have tested the `window.innerWidth < 681` part more, I have updated the answer with my fix. Can you confirm it works as intended now?

Comment: That was it! Confirmed working in responsive mode regardless of size dimensions and orientation via chrome dev tools.